# defective WAP or super congestion or am I missing something about channels 4 thru 8?

Tags: wireless-networking

I've been trying to improve the speed of my wifi so I'm systematically going through each channel and trying both 20 and 40.  The problem is I get a complete connection failure when I try channels 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8.  The clients can't even see it broadcasting on those channels.  My guess is the AP is defective?  But I'm hoping for some insight.

Comment: With a North American 2.4ghz router the only effective channels are 1,6, and 11.  As far as using wide channels (40 MHz), it's a great theory but in practice really doesn't work well due to hardware incompatibilities and 2.4ghz congestion.

Comment: @Tyson that doesn't really answer my Q, since 6 is in the 4-8 range that doesn't work, and 2, 3, 9, 10 all work fine.  Also, your conventional wisdom is consistent with many articles... but my results show the opposite.  1 and 11 are worst performers. 9 and 2 are best.  40 is FAR better than 20 except in 1 and 11, where it is same or little worse.

Comment: Wide channels are awesome when they work, they double your bandwidth. The problems start when you also connect a device that doesn't support the wide channel.  While channels other than 1 6 and 11 physically work, they are suspectable to interference from adjoining channels, meaning you have twice the chance strong nearby signals interfering with yours.  Don't forget WIFI is very dynamic, what is best at this moment in time, may not be in a hour or day.  You will find the most optimal consistent connection on a narrow channel 1,6, or 11.

Comment: How many devices have you tried? Did you use native wifi utility or a more complete software? If you're on Windows, you can try WiFi Scanner (http://lizardsystems.com/wi-fi-scanner/) to be sure.

Comment: A windows laptop, and Android phone and (as per this application) the mating directional wireless bridge that is pointing at the AP.  I tried InSSIDer for Windows and in all cases, I can't see the AP at all when it is connected on the mentioned channels.  I've since resigned to it being defective and not able to broadcast on those channels for some reason.